# Union of Sigma Fields (Borel)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Let $\Omega$ $= \mathbb R$, $A = [0,1]$ and $F_A$ be the $\sigma$ field generated by $A$. I believe that this means that $F_A$ is the sigma field generated by all open intervals of $A$. Is this correct?

Also, $B = [2,3]$ and $F_B$ be the $\sigma$ field generated by $B$.

I need to describe $F_A \cup F_B$. Would this just be the set generated by all open intervals inside $A$ or all open intervals inside $B$? I also believe that this isn't a sigma-field itself as there is no guarantee that the union of a countable number of sets remains inside the set.

Comment: The answer depends on what your unversal set $\Omega$ is. One defines **$\sigma-$ algebra of subsets of a set $\Omega$** generated by a family of sets, etc.

Comment: @geetha290krm $\Omega$ $= \mathbb R$

Comment: In that case $F_A=\{\emptyset, \mathbb R, A, A^{c}\}$ and $F_B=\{\emptyset, \mathbb R, B, B^{c}\}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Okay that makes sense. Was me stating that $F_A$ is generated by all open intervals of $A$ true? Is this even related to $Borel$ fields?